# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'screenName') - dynamic pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a common error when trying to pass data from parent to child component in next.js/react:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'screenName')
```

I believe that the error is being caused by the data not passing through but I am not able to see why. I have read next docs and my code is pretty textbook.

Here is the dynamic parent...

```
pages/artist/[artistId].js

import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import ArtistHeader from '../../components/ArtistHeader'
import UploadButton from '../../components/UploadButton'
import styles from '../../styles/artistPage.module.css'


export default function Artist ({ artist }) {

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      <Head>
          <title>{artist.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader data={artist}/>
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const results = await fetch(`REDACTED API ENDPOINT`).then (r => 
r.json())
  console.log(results)
  return {
    props: {
      artist: results[0]
    }
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const artists = await fetch('REDACTED API ENDPOINT').then (r => 
r.json())
  return {
    paths: artists.map(artist => {
        return {
          params: {
            artistId: JSON.stringify(artist.userId)
          }
        }
    
    }),
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

Here is the child component...

```
/components/ArtistHeader.js

import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '../styles/artistPage.module.css'

export default function ArtistHeader({ artist }) {
  return (
    <header className={styles.artistContainer}>
      <p>{artist.screenName}</p>
      <Image 
        className={styles.artistHeader}
        priority="true"
        src={artist.artistMainImg}
        alt={artist.screenName}
        width="1280px"
        height="200px"
        layout="intrinsic"
        objectPosition="center"
      />
    </header>
  )
}
```

This has to be something small but for the life of me I cannot see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did a typo in props name:

```
// your code
<ArtistHeader data={artist}/>

// should be
<ArtistHeader artist={artist}/>
//as
function ArtistHeader({ artist }) {...}
```